# The best strategies for implementing a dojo javascript client

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dojo

I would like to discuss the best strategies for implementing dojo javascript client with you.

I´m definitly new to dojo but familiar with js and webprogramming.

My strategie now, after doing my dojo researches, would be the following:

1. Build a GUI with dojo-Widgets (e.g. Borderlayout, Contentpane, Tabs, Buttons and so on). If there is no dojo-Widget, implement needed UI-Component by myself (e.g. div with onclick event as custom widget)
2. Cluster combined widgets which are the same type have the same functionality and write them into a seperate html (e.g. Tabs in a Tabcontainer - here I would write a tabs.html containing Contentpanes with a href on all other tabs (tab1.html, tab2.html,.. etc))
3. Glue the widgets and clustered widgets together and write the needed controllers for them. (e.g. controller with combines buttons and the tabs in the tabcontainer -> e.g. button should open new tab). A controller could match to only on widget too.
4. The model part could be some JSON received through an ajax request
   or better a dojo store.

This described strategie would implement the MVC pattern.

Would this be your rough strategie for implementing a dojo javascript client too?

What is your way of implementation using dojo with all it`s power?

Thx in advance.

Comment: I built a Dojo spa application which contained multiple flows, tabs, grids, widgets and panels and I used the MVC approach with decent success.

Comment: Why decent? What kind of issues did you run into?

Comment: if you are really interested in going hard core SPA development than I would recommend a must read `Single Page Web Applications: JavaScript end-to-end : by Michael Mikowski (Author), Josh Powell (Author)` which although does not use dojo ( uses jQuery, but you can substitute it with dojo ) will help you in architecting an SPA from ground-up. I have re-engineered the code to fit the dojo AMD style and really enjoyed the way the book is structured at least for a person who had no idea how to start an SPA. It will really help you focus on modularizing your code at a professional level.